# Force a Core Data Managed Object to load?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have an issue with Core Data where I am trying to load a second managed object from a relationship with the first object. But on some cases, that second managed object is a "fault" and the program crashes instead of loading the information associated with that second managed object. So is there any way to force a managed object to load into memory when it is accessed? Or does it have to wait until I try to directly access a property in the second managed object before it's data is loaded into memory?

Comment: Please show the error message and the code you are using to access the object. Isaac is right. Your "faulted" object is not what you think. Probably you have lost the reference to the first object or its reference to the second object is not configured correctly or not pointing to your second object.

Answer (score 0):

CoreData, in theory, generally handles the faulting and population of managed object's automatically and according to a variety of conditions.

Based on what you're describing, you shouldn't need to explicitly do anything such that the related managed object loads. When you access a related object, that managed objected should load in the same way as if you had accessed it directly itself.

So my guess would be that the issue isn't with faulting (although the object may indeed display fault status), but rather something else entirely. At this point the potential issues may be to broad to address specifically, but I would perhaps have  a look at your inverse relationships and make sure those are properly constructed...

Answer (score 0):

You will crash if you're trying to access a fault that has since been deleted in another context. CoreData will then be unable to get to the data of that fault.

You might also be accessing an object that's never been saved (unlikely, though).

If that's not the case, you're probably running into some threading problems. What's the exact error / exception you're seeing?